# Missing values in a mixed ANOVA in R

Tags: r, statistics, anova

So, in R, I am currently working with a dataset with missing values. For a t test and correlation, I am able to use either the `na.rm=TRUE` or the `use="complete"` commands.  However, when using an ANOVA (I am using `ezANOVA`), I am not sure what you would use.  Here is my code:

```
#reads in my file
bm=read.csv("Books_morality_2.13.csv", na.strings=".",header = TRUE) 

#t test works fine
t.test(data=bm, avg_ign_badX, Avg_int_neutX, alternative="two.sided",na.rm=TRUE)
```

Below I try running my ANOVA

```
bmanova=ezANOVA(data=bm, dv=Avg_int_neutX, wid=Subject.name, 
                within=Avg_int_neutX, between=Litfic_popfic_nobook)
```

The error I get is:

> "Error in ezANOVA_main(data = data, dv = dv, wid = wid, within =
>   within,  :  One or more cells returned NA when aggregated to a mean.
>   Check your data.".

Any suggestions for the "bmanova" portion of my code would be great. 
Thank you!

Comment: Try using `data=na.omit(bm)` inside `ezANOVA`.

Comment: Take only the complete cases before Anova: `bm <- bm[complete.cases(bm), ]`